# Спарсить таблицу с phpQuery

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

На сайте есть таблицы (их кол-во может менятся),внутри таблиц есть thead ( в нем только один tr>th) и tbody (в нем может быть сколько угодно tr и в каждой строке по 7 td). На картинке в tbody 2 tr:

[image: стуктура_таблицы]

Задача: необходимо парсить все данные из ячеек в удобной форме и записать в БД.
Как я это делал:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
foreach ($doc->find('.calendar-table') as $leagueTable) {
    $leagueTable = pq($leagueTable);
    $leagueName = $leagueTable->find('thead tr th')->text();
    ...
}
```

Далее необходимо зайти в tbody и пройти по всем tr и достать все ячейки. Я пробывал, но не совсем получается:

```
foreach ($leagueTable->find('tbody') as $tr) {
    $tr = pq($tr);
    $matchDate = $tr->find('tr td.date')->html();
    //и так далее все ячейки
}
$data[] = array('matchDate' => $matchDate,'awayTeam' => $awayTeam);
```

При var_dump получаю такой массив:

[image: массив]

То есть там где были две строки в tbody они "склеились" в одну. Хотелось бы получить массив awayTeam с ключами 0,1 где к примеру две команды(т.е было две строки).

Comment: что-то у вас не то с `$tr->find('tr td.date')`, по коду получается вы берете `tr` и ищите внутри еще `tr`. А по выводу, больше похоже на то, что ищется у `tbody` а не у `tr`, и тогда получается набор значений для всего столбца таблицы, а не для одной ячейки строки.

Comment: вам бы там сначала `foreach( ... ->find('tbody') as $tbody)` потом вложенный цикл для `$tbody->find('tr')` а потом уже получать значения дочерних `td`.

Comment: поправка к первому комменту, у вас переменная `$tr`  обозначет на самом деле `tbody` таблицы. поэтмоу `find("tr td.date")` возвращает действительно набор ячееек, контент которых склеивается в строку при вызове `html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так получилось. Проблемы были с объвлением массивов, и немного в цикле для phpQuery.

```html
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
foreach ($doc->find('.calendar-table') as $leagueTable) {
 $leagueTable = pq($leagueTable);
 $leagueTable->find('.tv-channel, .bet-td')->remove();
 $leagueTable->html();
 $leagueName = $leagueTable->find('thead tr th')->html();
 $leagueName = trim($leagueName);
 $awayTeam = array();
 $matchDate = array();
 $homeTeam = array();
 $homeTeamLogo = array();
 $awayTeamLogo = array();
 foreach ($leagueTable->find('tbody tr') as $tr) {
  $tr = pq($tr);
  $matchDate[] = $tr->find('td.date')->text();
  $homeTeam[] = $tr->find('td:nth-child(2) a')->text();
  $homeTeamLogo[] = $tr->find('td:nth-child(3) a img')->attr('src');
  $awayTeamLogo[] = $tr->find('td:nth-child(5) a img')->attr('src');
  $awayTeam[] = $tr->find('td:nth-child(6) a')->text();
 }


 $data[] = array(
 'leagueName' => $leagueName,
 'homeTeam' => $homeTeam,
 'homeTeamLogo' => $homeTeamLogo,
 'awayTeamLogo' => $awayTeamLogo,
 'awayTeam' => $awayTeam,
 );
}
```